# Creating Heart Rate Monitor Chart using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I am creating a web app using angular js and javascript. In My application I
 am Creating a heart rate monitor chart using chart.js. I want my chart should continuously animate. Here is My Code.

```
function getActualData() {
    var actualData = []
    for (var m = 0; m < 20; m++)
        actualData.push(45 + parseInt(Math.random() * 35))
    return actualData;
}

var ANIMATIONSTEPS = 200;

var myLineChart;
var labels;
var animationStep;
setInterval(function () {
    if (myLineChart === undefined) {
        var actualData = getActualData()

        var interpolationSteps = Math.ceil(ANIMATIONSTEPS / actualData.length);
        labels = []
        var data = []
        var blankData = []
        for (var i = 0; i < (actualData.length - 1); i++) {
            labels.push('')
            data.push(actualData[i])
            blankData.push(null)

            // push interpolation
            var difference = actualData[i + 1] - actualData[i];
            var interpolationStep = 1 / interpolationSteps;
            for (var j = 1; j < interpolationSteps; j++) {
                labels.push('')
                data.push(actualData[i] + difference * Chart.helpers.easingEffects["linear"](j * interpolationStep));
                blankData.push(null)
            }
        }
        labels.push('')
        data.push(actualData[i])
        blankData.push(null)

        var data = {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [
                {
                    strokeColor: "rgba(243, 118, 27, 1)",
                    data: blankData
                },
                {
                    strokeColor: "transparent",
                    data: data
                }
            ]
        };

        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
        myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
            animation: false,
            datasetFill: false,
            pointDot: false,
            datasetStrokeWidth: 5,
            showTooltips: false,
            scaleOverride: true,
            scaleSteps: 12,
            scaleStepWidth: 5,
            scaleStartValue: 30,
            scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
            scaleShowLabels: false,
        });

        animationStep = 0;
    }

    // the actual animation
    myLineChart.datasets[0].points[animationStep].value = myLineChart.datasets[1].points[animationStep].value
    myLineChart.update();
    animationStep++;

    // start new cycle
    if (animationStep >= labels.length) {
        myLineChart.destroy();
        myLineChart = undefined;
    }
}, 10)
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t795k4j3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to work with real time data which comes from any source and move back the current drawn line and draw new line on screen. Below Fiddle code may help you.

```
var context;
var cntText;
var cnt=0;
var start=0;
var mydata = [160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190,
                160,130,190,130,160,130,190,160,130,160,190,160,130,,160,190];

function init()
{
 context= myCanvas.getContext('2d');
 cntText=document.getElementById("data");
 context.fillStyle = "#737373";
 context.fill();


 /*
    var j=0;
    var lastx=0;
    var lasty=160;
 for(i=0;i<600;i++)
 {
    var p=j*5;
    drawLine(lastx,lasty,p,mydata[j],"#FF00FF");
    lastx=p;
    lasty=mydata[j];
    i=i+4;
    j++;
 }*/
 //move();
 //alert(mydata.length);
}
function drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2,color)
{
    context.beginPath();
    //context.fillStyle="#00E600";
    context.moveTo(x1,y1);
    context.lineTo(x2,y2);
    context.strokeStyle = color;
    context.lineWidth = 0.2;
    context.stroke();
}


function move()
{
     var j=0;
    var lastx=0;
    var lasty=160;
    var pos=0;
    //cnt=100;
    cleareData();
    start=cnt;
    if(cnt>120)
    {
        start=120;
        pos=cnt-120;
    }
    for(i=0;i<start;i++)
    {
        var p=i*5;
        drawLine(lastx,lasty,p,mydata[pos],"#FF00FF");
        lastx=p;
        lasty=mydata[pos];
        pos++;
    }
    //alert(cnt);
    //cntText.value=cnt;
    cnt=cnt+1;
}

function cleareData()
{
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
    for(i=0;i<600;i++)
     {

        drawLine(i,0,i,300,"#CCCCCC");
        i=i+19
     }

     for(i=0;i<300;i++)
     {

        drawLine(0,i,600,i,"#CCCCCC");
        i=i+19
     }
     drawLine(0,160,600,160,"#FF00FF");
 }
setInterval(move, 120);
```

init();

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/asvxqevy/1/